# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure in WAS 8.5.5.9

Tags: ssl, websphere, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

We have a single installation of WAS(8.5.5.9),with java of 1.8_64 and TLSv1.2 enabled on JVM. But when I run the code `sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols()`, it gives me `supported protocols=[TLSv1], which is V1.0.

When I check in Security > SSL certificate and key management, and under Related Items, click SSL configurations. ( such as CellDefaultSSLsetting , NodedefaultSSLsetting and any other SSLConfig), it shows 'TLSv1.2' as the protocol, under QoP settings.

To give you some background, am trying to connect to a dropwizard application which is configured with supported protocols as TLSv1.2 from an application deployed on WAS.

Since it tries to connect via TLS1, it gives javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.

```
    Error:
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:31)
at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:43)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.b(as.java:816)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:752)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:130)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:483)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:160)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:415)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:695)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:623)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:247)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:132)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:497)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:365)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:497)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:242)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:135)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.request(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:301)
```

Please guide me on how to fix the issue. 
Thanks,
Sravan Kumar

Comment: Presumably, there must be some place other than where you checked that is not set to TLSv1.2. In a lower level WAS configuration object, or directly in code maybe.

Comment: The stack suggests your going through some apache code, if that is the case there's a chance you are not using a WebSphere SSLContext, but using the JDK's default SSLContext.  This is an outbound call that is most likely not using a WebSphere create SSLContext and you must be using a level of they JDK that defaults TLSv1 for outbound.  You can try changing the JDK's default outbound protocol to TLSv1.2,  info here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1022279